# How do you evaluate and audit Central Authentication Service (CAS)?

Tags: authentication, audit, sso

This is in reference to Jasig's CAS software and I'm looking for a checklist to audit the state of security of a CAS implementation. While the Jasig site has a lot of documentation and their mailing list is active, is there any reference document or standardized checklist for security auditors to refer to?

Answer (score 1):

I have not seen a compliance guide for evaluating the security posture of CAS, but I have some urls that might be useful.

Securing Your New CAS Server
https://wiki.jasig.org/display/CASUM/Securing+Your+New+CAS+Server

Auditing and Statistics Via Inspektr
https://wiki.jasig.org/display/CASUM/Auditing+and+Statistics+Via+Inspektr

Enabling auditing will generate logs, but you might want to look at something to ingest logs and provide some analysis (like Splunk).

I hope this gives you a place to start.